# Can I jam the WiFi connection of other android phones nearby?

Tags: wi-fi

Is there any way to programmatically jam the WiFi signal of another Android phone? Or anything that comes close to this?

Comment: Are you physical stronger than them in case they form an angry crowd?

Comment: For the sake of argument, let's say yes.

Comment: Jamming WiFi could disturb innocent others nearby. Leave an imperative message on their facebook pages right before the meeting starts.

Comment: In the title I say the wifi signal of an Android phone (i.e. a specific android phone) not the WiFi router.

Comment: You can't jam only Android WiFi signal, because WiFi is just... a signal, the same WiFi any laptops, iPhone, Windows Phone, etc uses. Unless you have access to their phones and installed some kind of apps to remotely turn-off and disable the WiFi, it's impossible. I'd suggest to read for the alternative: [this](http://www.thekitchn.com/5-ways-to-deal-with-dinner-party-guests-who-are-glued-to-their-phones-203336) and [this](http://theweek.com/articles/479030/how-phone-stack-civilizing-dinners-friends).

Comment: A running microwave normally kills WiFi pretty good.  Just might be a little difficult to carry :D

Comment: *Every time I go out for a beer with my friends they pull out their phones and browse facebook. This annoys me to the point that I want to smash their phones against the floor.* -- I advise purging ([edit]) this. It isn't helpful to anyone. The relevant issue which can interest someone comes after this. I guess its inviting downvoting as well.

Answer (score 0):

***DISCLAIMER: I am not a lawyer, this information is provided AS-IS and without any claim to its accuracy or legality.***

If you know the SSID (name) of an access point their phones will automatically connect to (e.g. their home wifi), you can rename your own phone's hotspot to that and turn the hotspot on. If you don't turn data on they will not be able to access the internet.